# R: Grouped boxplot with 2 X-variables, in each group compare all samples vs. one X2 group

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I am trying to generate a grouped boxplot in ggplot2 with two x variables. This is straight-forward with

```
ggplot(boxplot_classes, aes(x=Group, y=Value, fill=Mutation)) + 
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8))
```

However, I do not need to compare the two subgroups defined by the second x-variable, but for each group defined by the first x-variable, I need to compare all samples in this group with one single subgroup from the second x variable.

Here an example. The data looks like this:

```
Value   Mutation    Group
32.00   Yes 1
5.00    no  1
18.00   no  1
3.00    no  1
16.00   no  1
14.00   Yes 1
28.00   Yes 1
28.00   Yes 1
49.00   Yes 1
15.00   Yes 1
43.00   no  2
49.00   Yes 2
40.00   Yes 2
17.00   Yes 2
9.00    no  2
31.00   Yes 2
8.00    Yes 2
43.00   no  2
50.00   Yes 2
48.00   Yes 2
11.00   Yes 3
42.00   no  3
0.00    Yes 3
15.00   Yes 3
8.00    no  3
1.00    Yes 3
41.00   no  3
15.00   no  3
4.00    no  3
31.00   Yes 3
```

I would like to generate a figure, were in each "Group" (in the example above: 1, 2, 3) two boxplots are generated: one for all samples in this "Group" and one only for those samples in this group, which also have mutation=="Yes". In the real data, many more "Groups are present".

I hope I could explain my problem well. Unfortunately I am somehow missing what the correct syntax is or how the data has to be rearranged.

Thank you very much for any help!

EDIT: I uploaded an example of the figure I am trying to generate at https://s28.postimg.org/hvq8pb25p/Folie1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we play with your data a bit, we can do it. Suppose your data is in `dat`:

```
dat_yes <- dat[dat$Mutation == 'Yes',] #subset only Yes
dat_yes$Mutation_2 <- 'Yes' #add column
dat$Mutation_2 <- 'All' #add column

dat_full <- rbind(dat, dat_yes) #put together

#plot
ggplot(dat_full, aes(x = factor(Group), y = Value))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Mutation_2))+
    xlab('Group') + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1', name = 'Mutation')
```

First, we create a subset of your data called `dat_yes`, which only contains the rows with `Mutation == 'Yes'`. We then create a new column in `dat_yes` called `Mutation_2` which takes the value of `'Yes'` only. We then add a column to your original data called `Mutation_2` which only takes the value of `'All'`. Then, we `rbind` `dat` and `dat_yes` to create `dat_full`. Finally, we send `dat_full` to `ggplot`.

[image]

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Value = c(32, 5, 18, 3, 16, 14, 28, 28, 49, 15, 
43, 49, 40, 17, 9, 31, 8, 43, 50, 48, 11, 42, 0, 15, 8, 1, 41, 
15, 4, 31), Mutation = c("Yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no", 
"Yes", "Yes", "no", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "no", "Yes", "Yes", 
"no", "Yes", "no", "no", "no", "Yes"), Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Value", 
"Mutation", "Group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I was not aware of the "accept" function. It was my first post here. did it now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example plot that you desire?

You can try a combination of facet_grid() or facet_wrap() and subsetting data to get the Mutation == Yes part.

Try this:

```
plot_base<- ggplot(boxplot_classes, aes(x=data, y=Value, fill=Mutation)) + geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8)) + facet_grid(Mutation~Group)
```

Look at other options for facet_grid and facet_wrap to modify further.

To get Mutation == Yes part:

```
plot_base %+% subset(boxplot_classes, Mutation %in% "Yes")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response. T

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response. I tested the code your proposed on my data, but it generates only a boxplot for Mutation=Yes. This is not exactly what I am looking for. I would need two boxes per group, one for all samples in the group defined by x1 ("Group") and one only for those sample in this group which are also positive for the Mutation. Please excuse me for not explaining it properly before! I added a link to an example to my original post.